# django if in queryset is always false

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug            = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField()
    price           = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, default=39.99)
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_image_path,null=True, blank=True)
    featured        = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    active          = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    item_cart = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user        = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products    = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, blank=True)
    subtotal    = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    total       = models.DecimalField(default=0.00,max_digits=100,decimal_places=2)
    updated     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


"""
"""

def product_list_view(request):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    item     = OrderItem.objects.all()
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(request)
    print(item)
    context = {
        'product_list':  queryset,
        'cart'       :  cart_obj,
        'orderitem'       :  item
    }
    return render(request, "products/list.html", context)

  """hmtl page list.hmtl
     {% if obj in orderitem %} doesnt print else print allways 
  """    

  {% for obj in product_list %}
        <div class='col my-3'>
            {{obj.title}}
            {{obj.price}}
            {{orderitem}}
            {% if obj in orderitem %}
            <h1>in cart</h1>
            {% else %}
            <h5>delete</h5>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endor %}
```

orderitem = <QuerySet [<OrderItem: iphone 6s>, <OrderItem: hi>]>,
obj   = hi ,
in list.hmtl if obj in orderitem always shows error and also tried obj.title in orderitem
But always else statement is printed without any error
trying to check the product is in ordereditem...

Comment: item does not exists in your template, it is `orderitem`, so `{% if obj in orderitem %}`.

Comment: sry i typed wrong in stockoverflow@WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @SuryanBoophathy: but `obj` is a `Product` whereas `orderitem` is a collection of `OrderItem`s, hence it makes no sense that `obj` is in the `orderitem`.

Comment: how to check whether obj is in cart @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: why is `item_cart = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)` a `CharField` and not a `ForeignKey` to the `Cart` model?

Comment: item ,created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(item=product, item_cart=cart_obj) , to specify the cart the item in added to specific_cart @WillemVanOnsem